# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm trying to train LSTM network on data taken from a DataFrame.

Here's the code:

```
x_lstm=x.to_numpy().reshape(1,x.shape[0],x.shape[1])

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.LSTM(x.shape[1], return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_lstm.shape[1],x_lstm.shape[2])),
    keras.layers.LSTM(NORMAL_LAYER_SIZE, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.LSTM(NORMAL_LAYER_SIZE),
    keras.layers.Dense(y.shape[1])
])

optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta()

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=optimizer)
for i in range(150):
    history = model.fit(x_lstm, y)
    save_model(model,'tmp.rnn')
```

This fails with

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 1
  y sizes: 99
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

When I change model to

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.LSTM(x.shape[1], return_sequences=True, input_shape=x_lstm.shape),
    keras.layers.LSTM(NORMAL_LAYER_SIZE, return_sequences=True),
    keras.layers.LSTM(NORMAL_LAYER_SIZE),
    keras.layers.Dense(y.shape[1])
])
```

it fails with following error:

```
Input 0 of layer lstm_9 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 1, 99, 1200]
```

How do I get this to work?

x has shape of `(99, 1200)` (99 items with 1200 features each, this is just sample a larger dataset), y has shape `(99, 1)`

Comment: try x_lstm=x.to_numpy().reshape(x.shape[0],1,x.shape[1]) with input_shape in lstm equal to (x_lstm.shape[1],x_lstm.shape[2])

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the `Error` suggests, the `First Dimension` of `X` and `y` is different. `First Dimension` indicates the `Batch Size` and it should be same.

Please ensure that `Y` also has the `shape`, `(1, something)`.

I could reproduce your error with the Code shown below:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


# define sequences
sequences = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3],
             [1]
    ]

# pad sequence
padded = pad_sequences(sequences)
X = np.expand_dims(padded, axis = 0)
print(X.shape) # (1, 3, 4)

y = np.array([1,0,1])
#y = y.reshape(1,-1)
print(y.shape) # (3,)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(None, X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile (
    loss='mean_squared_error',
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))

model.fit(x = X, y = y)
```

If we observe the `Print` Statements,

```
Shape of X is  (1, 3, 4)
Shape of y is (3,)
```

This Error can be fixed by uncommenting the Line, `y = y.reshape(1,-1)`, which makes the `First Dimension` (`Batch_Size`) equal (**`1`**) for both `X` and `y`.

Now, the working code is shown below, along with the Output:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


# define sequences
sequences = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3],
             [1]
    ]

# pad sequence
padded = pad_sequences(sequences)
X = np.expand_dims(padded, axis = 0)
print('Shape of X is ', X.shape) # (1, 3, 4)

y = np.array([1,0,1])
y = y.reshape(1,-1)
print('Shape of y is', y.shape) # (1, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, return_sequences=False, input_shape=(None, X.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile (
    loss='mean_squared_error',
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001))

model.fit(x = X, y = y)
```

The Output of above code is :

```
Shape of X is  (1, 3, 4)
Shape of y is (1, 3)
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 0.2588
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f5b0d78f4a8>
```

Hope this helps. Happy Learning!

Comment: what are the prediction results?  Should there be one output value or three? do you use a threshhold value to determine 0 or 1