# Fitting model with matrix label (ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement a simple image to text network. For every image the NN has an output of 5 character and there are 23 possible characters, so my labels are 5x23. When I try to fit the model I get the following error

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
(...)
```

Passing just one example, the message is this

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 1
  y sizes: 5
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

How can I properly train the network for this task?

The model is the following

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(h, w, 1))
x = Conv2D(conv_filters, kernel_size, activation='relu')(input_layer)
x = MaxPooling2D((pool_size,pool_size))(x)
x = Conv2D(conv_filters, kernel_size, activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((pool_size,pool_size))(x)

x = Reshape(target_shape=(5,-1))(x)
x = Dense(5, activation='swish')(x)

fw = GRU(128, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)
bw = GRU(128, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal')(x)

bgru = add([fw, bw])
output = Dense(n_tokens, activation='softmax')(bgru)
```

Comment: Please show your input data

Comment: The input is a 47x90 black and white image with 1 channel

Comment: here is an example https://ibb.co/xHjC6ry

Comment: First dimension of `x `and `y` is different. First dimension indicates the `batch size` and it should be same. Please ensure that `y` also has the shape `(1, something)`. Please refer   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62261086/14290681) may help you. Thanks!