# Is there any variation as how TensorFlow treats its inner list as Tensors in its newer version?

Tags: python, tensorflow, attention-model

I am trying to use the attention model to translate dates from human-readable format to a machine-readable format. There are no issues in the training part but when I try with my own examples, I get errors which I think is due to the TensorFlow version and how it treats inner lists as Tensors

```
Example_dates = ['3 May 1979', '5 April 09', '21th of August 2016', 'Tue 10 Jul 2007', 'Saturday May 9 2018', 'March 3 2001', 'March 3rd 2001', '1 March 2001']
for example in Example_dates:
    
    source = string_to_int(example, Tx, human_vocab)
    source = np.array(list(map(lambda x: to_categorical(x, num_classes=len(human_vocab)), source)))
    source = source.reshape((1, ) + source.shape)
    prediction = mod.predict([source, s0, c0])
    prediction = np.argmax(prediction, axis = -1)
    output = [inv_machine_vocab[int(i)] for i in prediction]
    
    print("source:", example)
    print("output:", ''.join(output))
```

Error is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-068509ef2d7c> in <module>
      5     source = np.array(list(map(lambda x: to_categorical(x, num_classes=len(human_vocab)), source)))
      6     source = source.reshape((1, ) + source.shape)
----> 7     prediction = mod.predict([source, s0, c0])
      8     prediction = np.argmax(prediction, axis = -1)
      9     output = [inv_machine_vocab[int(i)] for i in prediction]


ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 1, 30000, 30000
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.
```

Thanks!

Comment: does this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62253289/valueerror-data-cardinality-is-ambiguous help ?

Comment: no...I tried that but still the same error

Comment: @MadhurBhattad, *Is there any variation as how TensorFlow treats its inner list as Tensors in its newer version?*, Were you able to execute code in older version? If yes, what is older version? Also can you share standalone code to replicate your issue, so that we can try to help you. Thanks!