# How do solve Data cardinality is ambiguous?

Tags: python, opencv, conv-neural-network, face-recognition

I am trying to build a face recognition CNN model. This is the code for creating the labels used below.

```
import numpy as np 

def my_label(image_name):
    name = image_name.split('.')[-3] 

    if name=="person1":
        return np.array([1,0,0])
    elif name=="person2":
        return np.array([0,1,0])
    elif name=="person3":
        return np.array([0,0,1])
```

I build my dataset into test images and train images using the code below.

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from create_label import my_label
from random import shuffle
from tqdm import tqdm

def my_data():
    data = []
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir("/home/odroid/Desktop/FYP/CNN/data")):
        path=os.path.join("/home/odroid/Desktop/FYP/CNN/data",img)
        img_data = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        img_data = cv2.resize(img_data, (32,32))
        data.append([np.array(img_data), my_label(img)])
    shuffle(data)  
    return data

data = my_data()

train = data[:480]  
test = data[480:]
X_train = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,32,32,1)
print(X_train.shape)
y_train = [i[1] for i in train]
X_test = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,32,32,1)
print(X_test.shape)
y_test = [i[1] for i in test]
```

After running this code, I got
X_train = [480,32,32,1]
X_test = [120,32,32,1]
I then import the dataset to my CNN model.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from keras.losses import SparseCategoricalCrossentropy
from create_data import X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(32,32,1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.8))
model.add(Dense(3))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True), metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(X_test, y_test))
```

After running, it shows:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 480
  y sizes: 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Hi can anyone give comments so that I can improve on the code?

Comment: Your question almost duplicates the folowing one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62253289/valueerror-data-cardinality-is-ambiguous